# Are network printers with 10Base-T/100Base-TX connectivity compatible with older Ethernet equipement?

Tags: ethernet, compatibility

> **Edit:** Solved. 10Bast-T/100Base-TX are old and widespread standards. It  is not a problem for 10-15 years old computers to communicate with current products (like printers) offering this type of connectivity. See u1686_grawity's answer below for
> details.

---

Having computers from the time of Windows 7 with RJ45 sockets, RJ45 Ethernet cables and a 10/100 Mbps Ethernet passive hub (Zyxel ES-108P), I am considering acquiring a network printer (Brother HL-L3270CDW), whose **wired network connectivity is mentioned as 10Base-T/100Base-TX**.

As far as I understand, the connector used by the 10Base-T/100Base-TX Ethernet protocol will remain same (RJ45), but I am **not sure about the backward compatibility** of 10Base-T/100Base-TX with my 10 years old equipement.

**Is the pinout within the RJ45 connectors is ensured to be same** (or at least compatible) **?**

Are there there other possible uncompatibilities that I should care about?

I must admit that I don't have the time to read the long technical papers about these standards.

Comment: It should work fine. Lots of people / companies use older printers because good ones last a very long time. Try it and see.

Comment: Thank you, John. My fear was the actual printer possibly using a new standard and wiring, but 10Base-T/100Base-TX seems nothing else than the good old Ethernet standard at up to 100 Mbit/s. For details, see u1686_grawity's and LPChip's answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and a 10/100 Mbps Ethernet passive hub (Zyxel ES-108P),

It's not passive and it's not even a hub. ZyXEL ES-108P is an active Ethernet switch.

Real Ethernet *hubs* largely disappeared from the market long before ES-108P was introduced, and they generally were active (powered) devices as well. (Like switches but with "Collision" LEDs.)

(Fully passive Ethernet hubs do exist but are very rarely used; due to the way Ethernet works, they can only have 3 ports at most, as far as I know.)

> Are network printers with 10Base-T/100Base-TX connectivity compatible with older Ethernet equipement?
> [...]
> with my 10 years old equipement.

"10 years old" is not older, it's *newer*. Your printer's 100BASE-TX connectivity isn't something new – it's the same "Fast Ethernet" that  goes back to **1995** (it was the predecessor for 1000BASE-T "Gigabit Ethernet", which appeared in 1999), so your switch is a whole 18 years newer than the standard in question.

More to the point, 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX have always been the predominant standards for 10 & 100 Mbps Ethernet with RJ45 (there were others but none of them survived), and **your ES-108P is in fact a 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX switch** – it uses the exact same standards that your printer uses, so the question about compatibility is moot. (The [product specification](https://www.zyxel.com/global/en/products/switch/8-port-desktop-fast-ethernet-switch-es-108a-v3/specifications) confirms so.)

As for newer standards, however, practically all Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) equipment has backwards compatibility with both 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX; the GbE RJ45 connectors and cables still have twisted pairs on the same pins, and GbE equipment will correctly negotiate 100M mode with older equipment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear, detailed and expert answer, which makes me discover me that I was improprerly using the term "Ethernet hub" instead of "Ethernet switch", and their difference. Also happy to learn that "10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX" are old standards that are still in use. The need for clarification came from oddities like mSATA and mPCIe cards : same form factor, same physical connector, but electrically different. I was afraid that the similar thing could possibly exist for RJ45 connectors, which different pinout layouts. Your answer has reassured me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the same certainly does exist for RJ45 connectors – though mostly for _other_ things besides Ethernet; the same RJ45 is or has been used for analog telephone (like a bigger RJ11), for ISDN, for Token Ring, for RS-232 serial ("Cisco console cable"), etc., etc. (Which is the same situation as mSATA vs mPCIe really.) When it comes to Ethernet specifically, though, most RJ45-using Ethernet devices are compatible (with "passive PoE" being the major exception).

Answer (score 1):

The RJ45 connector has not changed for a really long time, and only the cable itself has been upgraded to higher standards to allow for faster speeds.

An RJ45 connector is backwards compatible, and the network protocol will test its maximum capable speed and converse using that speed.

So if an RJ45 connection on one side allows for 1000mbit, it means it will be a 10/100/1000 connection. If the other end is only 10/100, it will connect as 100mbit on both ends.

So if you ensure that you at least use a CAT-5 cable, then you are ensured of reaching at least 100 mbit.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer in addition to the one provided by u1686_grawity. Good to know that there is a continuity in the backward compatibility of this protocol and that equipements the 1000mbit version are able to communicate with those limited to 100mbit. Cheers.